# Testing a UIAnimation with KIF

Tags: kif-framework

Short: Is there a way to test if an animation is done the way it should with KIF,

Long: In iOS, if you animate a UIView is there a way to "test" the animation in KIF, or at least wait for the end of the animation, or alternatively wait for a UIView to be in a certain position?

Answer (score 1):

Use `stepToWaitForViewWithAccessibilityLabel`, such like waiting the network loading finish, bring back response, and show it to the paging scroll view, then I can start to swipe it.

```
[scenario addStep:[KIFTestStep stepToWaitForViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"pagingScrollView"]];
[scenario addStep:[KIFTestStep stepToSwipeViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"pagingScrollView" inDirection:KIFSwipeDirectionLeft]];
```

So after your animation done, present a AccessibilityLabel like `animatedDonePresentView`.

Comment: Not sure if I follow, so you are suggesting that I set the accessibility label in the code "on completion" of the animation, this way I can "wait" for the animation to finish, right?

Comment: Yes, that's how I did for testing pull to refresh view. In my - (void)pullToRefreshViewDidFinishLoading:(SSPullToRefreshView *)view I gave it view.accessibilityLabel = @"pullToRefreshViewDidFinishLoading" and wait for it.

Comment: Fantastic, do you have any clever way to test if the animation did happen the way you wanted it, like the duration of the animation was right or the direction of movement, or speed or things like that?